# Can I modify whitespace mode to distinguish hard and soft newlines?

Tags: whitespace-mode, buffer-display-table

Currently, [whitespace.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace) shows me newline characters by changing the display table to show a `$` at the end of lines.

I don't actually find this useful, so I disable it while I enjoy the many other benefits of `whitespace-mode`.

When I'm composing emails in `message-mode` I want to show the newline characters that have the `'hard` text property, because it affects how the flowed text shows up.

Can I hack this distinction into the display table logic of `whitespace-mode`?  My backup plan relies on `longlines-show-hard-newlines` but I'd prefer to extend  whitespace.el if possible.

Comment: I would have thought just adding `newline` and `newline-mark` to `whitespace-style` when entering message-mode would do it, but upon checking it seems `whitespace-style` is not buffer local.

Comment: I am able to toggle the `whitespace-style` in `message-mode`.  I personally use `whitespace-newline-mode` for this, but of course there are other ways to do it.  I find this toggle uses one face for every newline - it hacks the display table to show a fontified "$\n" whenever the text has a "\n".  The question is whether I can modify this display table logic to distinguish on other criteria, like text properties.  Does that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very ugly solution. First, define a function to find hard newlines such that it can be used by font-lock-mode:

```
(defun whitespace-find-hard-newlines (end)
  (search-forward "\n" end t)
  (while (and (not (memq 'hard (text-properties-at (match-beginning 0))))
       (search-forward "\n" end t)))
  (memq 'hard (text-properties-at (match-beginning 0))))
```

Here is what I used in my `*scratch*` buffer to test it. The switch to `fundamental-mode` made sure everything got initialized properly.

```
(progn
  (fundamental-mode)
  (text-mode)
  (longlines-mode)
  (whitespace-mode)
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil
    '((whitespace-find-hard-newlines 0 '(background-color . "#eee") t))))
```

Why is it ugly? Because adding a background color to the "newline" will create a light grey line to the right edge of the window. It looks ugly. You can't use the foreground color because there is nothing there to highlight. The $ sign that you're seeing comes from a display table and that only works on *characters*. On the character level, however, the hard and soft newlines don't differ.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm still learning the ins-and-outs of font lock keywords.  I'll play with this later and probably accept it - I'm fine with ugly solutions.

Comment: This makes sense and works as advertised!  I'll keep playing with it, but in the meantime, this is perfect for me.

Comment: I tried this, but it makes my Emacs 25 get stuck in an infinite loop in `font-lock-fontify-keywords-region`.  (`whitespace-find-hard-newlines` itself terminates as it's supposed to.)  I'll try to debug this and figure out why it happens, but any insights are welcome.